Redirecting all http(s?) traffic from one domain to another in Nginx
I have two domains (example_123.com and example_abc.com), and I've set up the newer one (example_abc.com) just the other day.
Everything works fine, all http traffic gets redirected to https://example_abc.com. In other words, as expected, any variant of example_abc.com will redirect to the secure https version.
Then, I noticed that if I visit my older domain, example_123.com, it also works (because of the DNS settings at my domain provider, which I haven't changed). So I decided to just redirect from example_123.com to example_abc.com.
However, I've only managed to get some variants working.
These redirect as expected:
http://www.example_123.com
www.example_123.com

These do not:
http://example_123.com
example_123.com
https://www.example_123.com

Here's a skimmed version of my config:
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example_abc.com

server {
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name example_abc.com www.example_abc.com;

        if ($host = https://example_123.com) {
                return 301 https://example_abc.com$request_uri;
        }

        if ($host = example_123.com) {
                return 301 https://example_abc.com$request_uri;
        }

        location / {
                root /srv/www/front/dist;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }


        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example_abc.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example_abc.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
        if ($host = www.example_abc.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        if ($host = example_abc.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        server_name example_abc.com www.example_abc.com;
        listen 80;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

Here I do checks for $host = https://example_123.com and $host = example_123.com, which, now that I'm writing it out, explains why only two variants of example_123.com (listed above) correctly redirect to example_abc.com.
How can I get ALL traffic from example_123 to redirect to https://example_abc.com?
